# Firestore empty result count as read?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to know if you fetch documents but there is no document to return, does this count as read at least once or count nothing which doesn't increase price?
I've been searching but I couldn't find the answer.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the official firebase documentation it clearly states that.

**Minimum charge for queries**
There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#minimum-charge